# Why does my Android app not request permissions on install?

Tags: android, android-permissions

When installing the APK, it shows the app doesn't require special permissions.

When launching the camera inside the app, it asks the user whether they'd like to allow the app to access the camera, which is fine.

When trying to use the microphone, it does not ask and force quits due to permission issues.

EDIT (Clarification): Why is the app not requesting these permissions?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lbu.c3369131.noter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="23"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
```

Comment: @tynn why is it not requesting the permissions?

Comment: Perhaps you are not calling `requestPermissions()`, asking for `RECORD_AUDIO`. On Android 6.0+ devices, with a `targetSdkVersion` of 23+, you have to ask for `dangerous` permissions yourself. Also note that you cannot hold `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT`, unless you are building your own custom ROM or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare you've saved me again! Please do write that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Android 6.0, with a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher, you need to call `requestPermissions()` for all `dangerous` permissions, in addition to having `<uses-permission>` elements for them in the manifest. When and where you request the permissions from the user (on first run, when the user clicks the Big Red Button, etc.) is up to you.

In your case, it sounds like you requested `CAMERA` this way, but failed to request `RECORD_AUDIO`. Requesting those separately may make sense, particularly if you are operating both the still camera and recording videos, as you do not need `RECORD_AUDIO` for photos. So, for example, in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/tutorial/finish/RuntimePermTutorial), I request `CAMERA` (and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) on first run, but I only ask for `RECORD_AUDIO` when the user specifically asks to record a video.

Failing to request a `dangerous` permission at runtime, then using some API protected by that permission, usually results in a `SecurityException`.